# Find the highest number in a table

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html-table

I have a table on my Wordpress webpage. I want to find the highest, lowest and average price in this table. The problem is the prices are shown in a `<span>` with a  class. (Please see the example on the following link)

http://jsfiddle.net/c69uf1xt/

```
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>01-12-2018</td>
<td class="wpt_price" id="price_value_id_1306" data-price_html="
<del>
<span class=&quot;woocommerce-Price-amount amount&quot;>
<span class=&quot;woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol&quot;>€</span>10.00</span>
</del> 
 <ins>
 <span class=&quot;woocommerce-Price-amount amount&quot;>
  <span class=&quot;woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol&quot;>€</span>7.00</span>
</ins>
 "> 
<span class="wpt_product_price">
<del>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>10.00</span>
</del> 
<ins>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>7.00</span>
</ins></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Is there any way to find these numbers with Javascript, or is that too complex to ask for?

I hope to hear from you.

Comment: These are really easy things to do in jquery. Ill try to come up with something in pure JS but ocnsider using jQuery if you're planning on doing more of these tasks.

Comment: Hey Rob, welcome to SO. You can definitely accomplish this through JavaScript using query selectors (I'd suggest [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and the [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property. You'll need to use some string manipulation and turn your values into [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)s. Try hacking around, and post an example of what you've done with a specific question when you need additional help. Best of luck.

Comment: Is it just the prices in the `data-price_html` attribute you want to include for each row? In the `del` _and_ `ins` elements?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. The code from @DennisLukas worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, getting all the prices into an array of Floats. this way you can manipulate the data easier.

```
var pricesarray = document.getElementsByTagName("ins");
var prices = [];

for(index = 0;index<pricesarray.length;++index){
    prices.push(parseFloat(pricesarray[index].innerText.replace("€","")));
}
```

Then getting the Highest and lowest numbers

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(Math,prices ); 
var lowest = Math.min.apply(Math,prices );
```

for the average we need to reduce and write a function to reduce the array into a sum, then divide it by the length of the array

```
var sum = prices.reduce(add, 0);

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var average = sum/prices.length;
```

And there we have it.

```
> lowest 
4 
> highest 
11 
> average
7.333333333333333
```

Comment: Also, If this was the answer you were looking for, please consider clicking the green checkmark to the left to mark this post as the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! So happy now. I had to do a few little adjustment and some extra code (because i had to exclude a few numbers)! But it's working now!